# Modifying items in dictionary without affecting the original object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
    Dictionary<int, int> test = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    test.Add(1,1);
    test.Add(2, 2);

    Dictionary<int, int> test2 = test;
    test2.Remove(1);
```

Removing item from *test2* is removing the item from *test* object too. Can you tell me how to modify items from *test2* without affecting *test*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

test2 and test are the same reference to the same object (dictionary). Instantiate a new dictionary for test2.

```
Dictionary<int, int> test2 = new Dictionary<int, int>(test);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you assign `test` to `test2` via `test2 = test` you're assigning a *reference* to that object, meaning they both point to the same location in memory. Any changes on `test2` will take effect on `test`. You need to use the `new` keyword e.g:

```
Dictionary<int,int> test2 = new Dictionary<int,int>(test);
```